# Displaying attributes in Dash/Plotly results in KeyError

Tags: python, networkx

I'm trying to visualize references from documents. For this, I have `Elements.csv`, which looks like this:

```
Doc,Description,DocumentID
SOP Laboratory,This SOP should be used in the lab,10414
Visual Design,Basics for Visual Design,1200139348
GMP,Good Manufacturing Practises,4638261
Windows PC manual,This manual describes how to use Windows PCs,271922
```

In `Connections.csv`, I have the references:

```
Source,Target
SOP Laboratory,Windows PC manual
SOP Laboratory,GMP
Visual Design,Windows PC manual
```

I.e. there is a reference in `SOP Laboratory`, which points to `Windows PC manual`, etc.

The code I use to visualize this network works with Dash/Plotly:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

## Dash setup

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)


## Data

edges = pd.read_csv('Connections.csv', encoding="utf8")
nodes = pd.read_csv('Elements.csv', encoding="utf8")


## Graph

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges, 'Source', 'Target')
nx.set_node_attributes(G, nodes.set_index('Doc')['Description'].to_dict(), 'Description')
nx.set_node_attributes(G, nodes.set_index('Doc')['DocumentID'].to_dict(), 'DocumentID')

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

for node in G.nodes:
    G.nodes[node]['pos'] = list(pos[node])

traceRecode = []

index = 0
for edge in G.edges:
    x0, y0 = G.nodes[edge[0]]['pos']
    x1, y1 = G.nodes[edge[1]]['pos']
    trace = go.Scatter(x=tuple([x0, x1, None]), y=tuple([y0, y1, None]),
                        mode='lines',
                        hoverinfo='none',
                        line={'width': 2},
                        marker=dict(color='#000000'),
                        line_shape='spline',
                        opacity=1)
    traceRecode.append(trace)
    index = index + 1

node_trace = go.Scatter(
    x=[],
    y=[],
    hovertext=[],
    text=[],
    mode='markers+text',
    textposition="bottom center",
    hoverinfo='text',
    marker=dict(
        showscale=True,
        colorscale='Agsunset',
        reversescale=True,
        color=[],
        size=20,
        colorbar=dict(
            thickness=15,
            title='Node Connections',
            xanchor='left',
            titleside='right'
        ),
        line=dict(width=0)))

index = 0
for node in G.nodes():
    x, y = G.nodes[node]['pos']
    # hovertext = "Document Name: " + str(G.nodes[node]['Doc']) + "<br>" + "Document ID: " + str(G.nodes[node]['DocumentID'])
    # text = nodes['Doc'][index]
    node_trace['x'] += tuple([x])
    node_trace['y'] += tuple([y])
    # node_trace['hovertext'] += tuple([hovertext])
    # node_trace['text'] += tuple([text])
    index = index + 1

for node, adjacencies in enumerate(G.adjacency()):
    node_trace['marker']['color']+=tuple([len(adjacencies[1])])
    node_info = adjacencies[0] #+ ' (' +str(adjacencies[1]) + ')' #+' (' +str(len(adjacencies[1])) + ' connections)'
    node_trace['text']+=tuple([node_info])

traceRecode.append(node_trace)

figure = {
    "data": traceRecode,
    "layout": go.Layout(title='Document Overview', showlegend=False, hovermode='closest',
                        margin={'b': 40, 'l': 40, 'r': 40, 't': 40},
                        xaxis={'showgrid': False, 'zeroline': False, 'showticklabels': False},
                        yaxis={'showgrid': False, 'zeroline': False, 'showticklabels': False},
                        height=1000,
                        clickmode='event+select',
                        annotations=[
                            dict(
                                ax=(G.nodes[edge[0]]['pos'][0] + G.nodes[edge[1]]['pos'][0]) / 2,
                                ay=(G.nodes[edge[0]]['pos'][1] + G.nodes[edge[1]]['pos'][1]) / 2, axref='x', ayref='y',
                                x=(G.nodes[edge[1]]['pos'][0] * 3 + G.nodes[edge[0]]['pos'][0]) / 4,
                                y=(G.nodes[edge[1]]['pos'][1] * 3 + G.nodes[edge[0]]['pos'][1]) / 4, xref='x', yref='y',
                                showarrow=True,
                                arrowhead=4,
                                arrowsize=2,
                                arrowwidth=1,
                                opacity=1
                            ) for edge in G.edges]
                        )}

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(figure=figure
    ),
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I found this code from this [Github repo](https://github.com/jhwang1992/network-visualization).

This results in:
[Wrong arrows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9c0ut.png)

However, the direction of the error is wrong. (See the red arrow for the correct direction.)

What I want to achieve is this ("Bob" and "Type1" from the Github repo), i.e. display the document name, description and ID when hovering over the node:
[goalAttributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLSs0.png)

However, when I comment lines out, like this

```
index = 0
for node in G.nodes():
    x, y = G.nodes[node]['pos']
    hovertext = "Document Name: " + str(G.nodes[node]['Doc']) + "<br>" + "Document ID: " + str(G.nodes[node]['DocumentID'])
    text = nodes['Doc'][index]
    node_trace['x'] += tuple([x])
    node_trace['y'] += tuple([y])
    node_trace['hovertext'] += tuple([hovertext])
    node_trace['text'] += tuple([text])
    index = index + 1

# for node, adjacencies in enumerate(G.adjacency()):
#     node_trace['marker']['color']+=tuple([len(adjacencies[1])])
#     node_info = adjacencies[0] #+ ' (' +str(adjacencies[1]) + ')' #+' (' +str(len(adjacencies[1])) + ' connections)'
#     node_trace['text']+=tuple([node_info])
```

However, this results in an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rothstem\Desktop\LearnDash\StackEX\app.py", line 73, in <module>
    hovertext = "Document Name: " + str(G.nodes[node]['Doc']) + "<br>" + "Document ID: " + str(G.nodes[node]['DocumentID'])
KeyError: 'Doc'
```

which I don't quite understand, since `'Doc'` is defined above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During your graph creation you created the node attribute `"Description"`:

```
nx.set_node_attributes(G, nodes.set_index('Doc')['Description'].to_dict(), 'Description')
```

So you simply need to replace `"Doc"` with `"Description"`:

```
hovertext = "Document Name: " + str(G.nodes[node]['Description']) + "<br>" + "Document ID: " + str(G.nodes[node]['DocumentID'])
```