# Follow-up to Displaying attributes in Dash/Plotly results in KeyError

Tags: python, networkx

After a helpful answer to my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62809930), I decided to use internal data (which I can't share here). The internal data follows the same format as the mock data. I simply copied the data over to the same working directory, making sure that the new data has the same format, i.e. same column headers, etc. I used DiffChecker to make sure that `app.py` (from my original post) matches the Proof of Concept (`appPOC.py`). The internal data has more than 600 nodes, and more than 3000 edges.

The code to make the interactive dashboard is the same as the one I used for my [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62809930). However, this time I run into this `KeyError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "appPOC.py", line 75, in <module>
    hovertext = "Document Description: " + str(G.nodes[node]['Description']) + "<br>" + "Document Name: " + str(G.nodes[node]['DocName']) + "<br>" + "Document ID: " + str(G.nodes[node]['DocumentID'])
KeyError: 'Description'
```

The data itself should be fine, as I can plot a network without the hovering text next to the node.

To summarize: `app.py` can plot the mock data, `appPOC.py` (which is identical, but has a different file name) can't plot the internal data. This leads me to believe that there is something wrong with the internal data in the `CSV` file.

**Edit**: I figured out that if the target is not listed in the elements, the graph fails to be drawn. Is there anyway to create a node automatically (like in Gephi) if the (target) node is not defined in the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NetworkX` creates nodes for from- and to-nodes of each edge. Hence, with

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges, 'Source', 'Target')
```

you're graph has all possible nodes. However, with

```
nx.set_node_attributes(G, nodes.set_index('Doc')['Description'].to_dict(), 'Description')
nx.set_node_attributes(G, nodes.set_index('Doc')['DocumentID'].to_dict(), 'DocumentID')
```

you only fill the node attributes `'Description'` and `'DocumentID'` for those in your nodes data frame. A simple workaround is to replace the

```
str(G.nodes[node]['Description'])
```

with

```
str(G.nodes[node].get('Description', ''))
```

and similarly for `'DocName'` and `'DocumentID'`. More information on the get method you find at: [Why dict.get(key) instead of dict[key]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey)
Basically, we use that `networkx` uses `dict` to store values and make use of the `get` method, which allows to supply a default value.

#### A simple reproducible and minimal example

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.karate_club_graph()
# all nodes in this graph have the node attribute 'club' filled
# we add a node without this node attribute
g.add_node("Test")
print(g.nodes[0]["club"])
# 'Mr. Hi'
# print(g.nodes["Test"]["club"]
# results in KeyError: 'club'
print(g.nodes["Test"].get("club", ""))
# ''
```